# How do I create a text box in HTML?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I want to create a text box exactly like the message box used for these questions here on stackoverflow.

Is there a HTML code for this, supported by IE9 or higher? Or do I need to incorporate other specialized code?

Comment: like the message box used for **which** messages?

Comment: "used for these messages" sorry, what messages?

Comment: Did you try Googling "html text box"?

Comment: I imagine that he means posting a question or answer on StackOverflow

Comment: Definitely use Java for this. But note that text boxes are supported in IE 9, but not IE 10.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Please don't mislead.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, please continue being hilarious

Comment: @bPratik: sorry, it was a bit snarky. I figured the question would be closed or edited to be clearer pretty soon.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I'm all for snarky comments! But please close them off with clarification. If you are a newbie, it's not helpful! :)

Comment: I mean the text boxes used to type the questions in im sure that doesn't take a rocket scientist to figure out...

Comment: @NathanTaylor, this link might be of use: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEJ9HrZq7Ro#t=0m16s

Comment: @NathanTaylor: when asking strangers on the internet for help, it’s polite to explain your question clearly, so that we have less work to do in order to help you. (That said, it’s also polite to ask for clarification rather than add snarky, misleading comments, so who am I to talk?)

Comment: @NathanTaylor: “am I expected to know all the Jargon and correct terminology to actually post questions on here” — no, but you need to be clear with your questions. Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions a day. If you’re not prepared to put a bit of effort into your questions to make them easy to understand, don’t expect people to be keen to put effort into helping you. No-one gets paid for answering questions here. See further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I put all the effort I can into all of my questions I have like 3 weeks experience with coding I haven't even scratched the surface how can I make my questions easier to understand if I don't understand the terminology or wording myself?

Comment: @NathanTaylor: Taking this question as an example, the problem wasn’t inaccurate coding terminology. The problem was that the phrase “the message box used for these messages” was too vague. A better phrasing would have been “the message box used for asking questions here on Stack Overflow”, because now your meaning is explicit, and the reader doesn’t need to infer anything from context.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That is a fair point and I changed it.. but now ive been locked out of asking further questions so I cant really do anything about it...

Comment: @NathanTaylor: ah, I see. Well, I’ve upvoted your edited questions, so that might get the ban lifted. If not, and if Stack Overflow still seems worthwhile to you, you might want to come back see if you can answer some questions as you learn more about coding (there are loads asked about HTML, CSS and JavaScript, often very beginner-y). If your ask ban does get lifted, have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Thanks @PaulD.Waite that's really helped me out i'll try my utmost to be clearer in the future :)

Comment: @NathanTaylor: hi Nathan! If you want to ask another question, please use the “Ask Question” button in the top-right-hand corner of the page. Changing this question to a different question entirely means that its answers make no sense. On Stack Overflow, questions and answers are meant to stay, as a resource for other developers.

Comment: @NathanTaylor: I’ve rolled your edit back. If you click on the “Edited” link above my username at the bottom of the question, you can copy your edited version to post as a new question.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: I cant cus im blocked again...

Comment: @NathanTaylor: then you’ll have to wait until you’re unblocked, I’m afraid.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm under the impression that it doesn't lift after time... and I cant really answer questions so what should I do?

Comment: @NathanTaylor: I’m not sure. (I don’t have experience with account blocking.) Maybe open a new account and try again, making sure you pay attention to both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and feedback on your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question box on Stack Overflow is an HTML`<textarea>`, but enhanced with a JavaScript... thingy called [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/). (Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121982)

The JavaScript is what adds the buttons above it to let the user add Markdown syntax without typing.

I’m not sure which browsers PageDown supports.

Answer (score 1):

A Textarea?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

```
<textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50">Write something here</textarea>
```

Comment: something like this but to write in as part of a form

Comment: @NathanTaylor, if you need it as part of a form, just stick it somewhere after `<form>` and before `</form>`!  As you've said, this isn't rocket science. Did you bother trying to Google this first???

Comment: Have a look at this for form elements - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp. But if you want to submit that data anywhere you'll need a Server-side language (PHP, ASP.NET for example)

Comment: @DerekHenderson I would've googled it but I already had an account on here and I checked w3schools.com which I must add is a great site and couldn't find it I thought it would be easier to consult people on here

Comment: @NathanTaylor, (1) SO is not a substitute for Google and people here don't tend to react so well when a question shows such little initiative as yours did. (2) w3schools is a horrible, horribly misleading site! You can find out more at http://www.w3fools.com/ and http://webdesign.about.com/b/2011/04/06/i-had-no-idea.htm and other sites.